# array assignment bash script is not working as expected

Tags: bash

i am trying to enter a few variables into array in bash script.
this is the code i wrote, but it does not do the job. the echo command returns an eroor message that the command KEYS[0] (for instance) not found.

```
curl https://www.gentoo.org/downloads/signatures/ | grep 0x | cut -d '>' -f3 | cut -d '<' -f1  | while read line; do
            KEYS[$i]=$line

            echo $(KEYS[$i])
            ((i++))
            done
```

I don't really mind about the echo, but the qustion is how can i use this array later on?

Thank you!

note: the OS is Cent OS 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax uses curly brackets, not the round ones:

```
echo ${KEY[i]}
```

(The dollar sign before `i` is optional).